react version in hoist-non-react-statics file generated after build
I'm using viteJS with React for my web app. after running the build command npm run build it generate a hoist-non-react-statics-DD3vAyqj.js in assets folder, my actual react version is v18.3.1 but in this fil @license React v16.13.1.
after a pentest, They notified me to upgrade the react version coming from this file (@license React v16.13.1) to v18.3.1 .
after some researche, hoist-non-react-statics is used by google recaptcha lib:

Is this possible or does it have no impact since I already use react 18.3.1
the hoist-non-react-statics use react-is@16.13.1
